# How to add a single custom field to every recipient of template using docusign ui

Tags: docusignapi

How can i add the same custom field to every recipient in template ?

Answer (score 0):

Recipient level custom field/values can be set only via API

Comment: You will be using DocuSign API, for instance if you want to add Recipient Level Custom Field then check `customFields` property [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create#signer)